Any automated way to view a network of pytest fixtures/functions defined in the conftest.py file?
I've inherited a large data science workflow (in python) that uses many functions scattered across many modules. Luckily for me, around 50% of these functions already have pytest coverage and make use of a conftest.py file which sets up tons of fixtures and mock objects for testing (dfs, dicts, lists, etc. with fake data). I'm responsible for creating the other 50% of tests.
However, most fixtures call a maze of other fixtures from within conftest or functions/classes from internal modules, and I'm having a very hard time reverse engineering a given fixture to see how it interacts with the other fixtures/functions to return the eventual object (usually a simple df, dictionary of mixed types, json, etc.).
For example, one of my fixtures that I think returns my desired dataframe (that I need as a mock in a new test) first calls another fixture from within conftest, which then calls an imported function from an internal module whose return is mocked by yet another fixture within conftest. Not too crazy but that's just one of the arguments passed to the original fixture, and there are three more which have a similar hierarchy of following down the rabbit hole to find what is actually being read in.
So what I'm after is a network or decision tree that'll lay out graphically how all the individual "pieces" in my test environment are interacting. Has anyone come across or created a good package that'll generate such an output for a pytest conftest.py file? Just to be more explicit, I'm picturing a CL tool that I pass my conftest.py file and it goes through all fixtures and imported functions and lays them out in some kind of 2D representation where connections between them are shown as arrows.

Navigating a complex web of fixtures and dependencies can indeed be challenging, especially when dealing with large data science workflows. Fortunately, there are some tools and techniques that can help you visualize the interactions between fixtures. Let’s explore a few options:
pytest --setup-plan:
You can use the --setup-plan option with pytest to get a detailed view of how fixtures are set up during test execution.
Run the following command in your terminal:
pytest --setup-plan
This will show you the order in which fixtures are set up and their dependencies.
While it won’t provide a graphical representation, it can help you understand the fixture chain.
pytest-fixture-tools:
The pytest-fixture-tools package provides a helpful visualization of fixture dependencies for individual tests.
Although it doesn’t create a static graph of fixture dependencies, it can still be useful for your purposes.
Here’s an example of how it looks:
+-------------------+
| test_something    |
+-------------------+
|
v
+-------------------+
| fixture_foo       |
+-------------------+
|
v
+-------------------+
| fixture_bar       |
+-------------------+
While this doesn’t cover the entire fixture hierarchy, it does show dependencies for each test.
Manual Exploration:
Sometimes, manually tracing fixture dependencies by examining the code and understanding how they interact is necessary.
Start with the fixture you’re interested in and follow the chain of dependencies.
Use comments or documentation to annotate your findings.
Dependency Graph Tools (Outside of pytest):
Although not directly integrated with pytest, you can use external tools to create dependency graphs.
Graphviz: Graphviz is a powerful tool for creating graphs. You can write a script to extract fixture dependencies and generate a Graphviz DOT file. Then, use Graphviz to render the graph.
NetworkX (Python): NetworkX is a Python library for creating, analyzing, and visualizing complex networks. You can build a network graph of fixtures and their dependencies using NetworkX.
Custom Scripting:
If you’re comfortable with scripting, consider writing a custom Python script that parses your conftest.py file and constructs a dependency graph.
You can use data structures like dictionaries or graphs to represent the relationships between fixtures.

I feel like there's a 95% chance that this was just generated with an LLM, but thanks for the advice. This didn't really solve my problem but I didn't know about this pytest command.
